# Handle single progressdialog with parallel multiple asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

In my Project I want to parallelly load the data from 3 different url's(webservice) while loading the page.

for this I use 3 different asynctask to load data.

I want to show the progress dialog message as "loading" when first asynctask is started and  close dialog after last asynctask is completed(until complete 3 tasks show progress dialog).

Please tell me the way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to handle this situation.

1. You can use a counter variable initialized with the number of tasks, and this counter gets decremented when an `AsyncTask` is complete. When the counter is 0, the `ProgressDialog` is dismissed. You can do this decrement and checking for progress dialog dismissal in each of the `AysncTask`'s `onPostExecute`.
2. You may not need the 3 different `AsyncTask`s. You can use a single `AsyncTask` with a [`CountDownLatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for `Thread` synchronization.

Comment: thank u rajesh, I will get success with u'r logic, I create one global variable in activity and every time I increase the value in postexecute() and check when the value reach to "3" I dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do is you can create an interface `OnThreadFinishListener` (with an `onThreadFinish()` method) and have your activity implement it. All of your `AsyncTask` should register itself to the listener so each time a thread finishes it calls the `onThreadFinish` method. in the onThreadFinish method it should check if there is still a thread running in the background (something like `if (asyncTask1.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING || asyncTask2.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ... )` )

If all are false then you can dismiss the `progress dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it as below:

```
//define progress dialog object globally in your parent class
ProgressDialog pd = null;
```

**AsyncTask1** `onPreExecute`:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "title", "loading", true);
```

**AsyncTask2**:

```
//do nothing
```

**AsyncTask3** `onPostExecute`:

```
if(pd!=null)
    pd.dismiss();
```

Comment: thank u for giving answer, but we cann't expect is which asyntask is loading last..

Comment: aren't you starting second task in first's onPostExecute?